# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property ans has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-lateinit

The `toPascalCase` function is intended to convert strings containing spaces or `-` to Pascal case.

Below is my code ->

```
fun toPascalCase(str: String): String {
    lateinit var ans: String

    for(i in str) {
        if(i != ' ' && i != '-') {
            ans += i
        }
    }
    return ans
}

fun main() {

toPascalCase("Harsh kumar-singh")

}
```

I have used the `lateinit` keyword before `ans` variable. In the for loop I have initialized the `ans` variable but still the compiler throws the following error ->

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property ans has not 
been initialized
at FileKt.toPascalCase (File.kt:10) 
at FileKt.main (File.kt:18) 
at FileKt.main (File.kt:-1)
```

Please help me with the code. Thank you

Comment: "In the for loop I have initialized the ans variable".  No, you haven't.  `ans += i` is equivalent to `ans = ans + i`, which reads the value _before_ setting it.  A `lateinit` var will hold `null` initially -- and you can't add that to anything, hence the error.  (`lateinit` makes no sense for local variables; it's only for properties that can't be initialised until after their object is, which is a relatively rare situation.  And even then, you still need to set a value before you use it.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `lateinit var`, you should use a simple var initializing it to an empty string.

```kotlin
fun toPascalCase(str: String): String {
    var ans = ""
    ...
```